# Doubt regarding equating coefficients of polynomial in modulo p

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

I was reading a book and I came across an argument like the following -

$$\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i \equiv \sum_{i=0}^nb_ix^i  \mod p$$

$$\implies a_i\equiv b_i \mod p \forall i$$

How to prove this ?
I have no idea how to approach this.

Comment: You might find helpful [various posts](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+formal+functional+polynomial) on *formal* polynomials vs. polynomial *functions*

Answer (score 2):

@Lucyfer, this is simply *definition* of equality in the **ring of polynomials** over a given fields, say. Passing to polynomial *functions* it can be very false. For example

$$f(x)=0\;,\;\;q(x)=x^2-x$$

are exactly the same function over $\;\Bbb F_2\;$, yet as *polynomials* in $\;\Bbb F_2[x]\;$ they're completely different.

Comment: You and I have dealt with different aspect’s of OP’s partial understanding. I do think your approach is essential.

Answer (score 1):

Take the difference of the two polynomials, $\sum(a_i-b_i)x^i$, which you’re being told is divisible by $p$. That is, it’s of the form $p\!\sum c_ix^i=\sum(pc_i)x^i$. Since this and your difference-polynomial are equal (as polynomials), their coefficients are the same. Thus $p|(a_i-b_i)$ for each $i$. It’s just a matter of understanding and using what $a\equiv b\pmod p$ means.